# MySQL Cluster Docker ndb_mgmd: [ERROR] unknown variable 'user=mysql'

Tags: mysql, docker, mysql-cluster

Hi I was following the official mysql cluster documentation for creating a MySQL cluster on Docker.

https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-cluster

However when I looked at the logs I can see that the management node and the data nodes are failing with the following error.

```
[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 7.6.18-1.2.2-cluster
[Entrypoint] Starting ndb_mgmd
MySQL Cluster Management Server mysql-5.7.34 ndb-7.6.18
ndb_mgmd: [ERROR] unknown variable 'user=mysql'
```

I have not configured any my.cnf or my-config.cnf files as I am just using the defaults. Any idea of what is happening?

Comment: have you defined user=mysql in docker file?

Comment: Hi, @MauritzSundell yes that was really helpful. Thank you for pointing me to the article.